# Unexpected results after optimizing switch case in Visual Studio with C#8.0

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Today while coding, visual studio notified me that my switch case could be optimized. But the code that I had vs the code that visual studio generated from my switch case does not result in the same outcome.

The Enum I Used:

```
public enum State
{
    ExampleA,
    ExampleB,
    ExampleC
};
```

After the following code runs the value is equal to 2147483647.

```
State stateExample = State.ExampleB;
double value;

switch (stateExample)
{
    case State.ExampleA:
        value = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes((long)2147483646), 0);
        break;
    case State.ExampleB:
        value = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes((long)2147483647), 0);
        break;
    case State.ExampleC:
        value = BitConverter.ToInt16(BitConverter.GetBytes((long)2147483648), 0);
        break;
    default:
        value = 0;
        break;
}
```

But when visual studio optimized the switch case, the value becomes 2147483648.

```
State stateExample = State.ExampleB;
double value = stateExample switch
{
    State.ExampleA => BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes((long)2147483646), 0), //Commenting this line results in correct value
    State.ExampleB => BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes((long)2147483647), 0),
    State.ExampleC => BitConverter.ToInt16(BitConverter.GetBytes((long)2147483648), 0),
    _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
};
```

This is just the code with information that reproduced the erroneous output and not actual code that is run in production. What I found weird was that if I comment out the line `State.ExampleA` in the last code block the correct value is written.

My Question is: Is this a bug? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: [Casting each case to `double`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ot2p5L) will provide the correct result. However, I have no clue why

Comment: I'd suggest the refactor is invalid since it introduces an intermediate cast to `Single` to be the type of the whole expression and that loses some precision. It has to pick a single best type from `Single`, `UInt32` and `Int16`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This highlights the difference between a *statement* and an *expression*. The switch you had before, was a switch *statement* and this was the assignment that got run.

```
value = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes((long)2147483647), 0);
```

Here you are converting an `uint` (right hand side) to a `double` (left hand side). You were actually doing a different conversion in each branch of your switch statement, and this was fine, because well, they are separate assignment statements.

Compare that to what you are doing after the optimisation: the switch statement became a switch *expression*. And *expressions* have a single *type*. What is type of this expression?

```
stateExample switch
{
    State.ExampleA => BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes((long)2147483646), 0), //Commenting this line results in correct value
    State.ExampleB => BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes((long)2147483647), 0),
    State.ExampleC => BitConverter.ToInt16(BitConverter.GetBytes((long)2147483648), 0),
    _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
}
```

Each branch of the switch returns a different type - `float`, `uint` and `short` respectively. **So C# needs to find a type to which all three of these can be implicitly converted**. And `float` is found. C# can't just "figure out" what the switch returns at runtime and work out the conversion to perform "dynamically".

The things returned in each branch has to be first converted to a `float`. Therefore, the type of the *whole* expression is `float`. Finally, you assign the `float` to `value`, which is a `double`.

So the overall conversion is `uint` -> `float` -> `double`, causing a loss of precision.

Comment: I wish there was some kind of information somewhere in visual studio that states this change or that it detects this better. After this incident I will rather think twice before blindly using the optimize features of visual studio...

Comment: @JuckoThirteen Indeed, those optimization suggestions are just that - suggestions.  In many cases, they should not be followed.  This particular instance, for example, does not work in all versions of C#.  I work with the Unity engine a lot, which does not support pattern matching at all, but VS still happily suggests this change, which won't even compile in the target platform.

Comment: @Darrel Are you sure that you have incorrectly set the target language version? Both Roslyn and R# are generally good at only offering language version applicable refactorings. Apart from that the whole implicit conversion from int to float always seemed like a strange choice to me for exactly these reasons - lossful implicit conversions are stupid.

Comment: @Voo Unity specifically sets up the project files automatically, so it'd be weird if it was set to the wrong version.  This might be more a Unity problem than a VS problem admittedly.

Comment: @Darrel Probably indeed a unity issue then. VS does consider the [default language version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) correctly and does not offer the refactoring hint for say .NET 4.5.2 - I just tried (with netcoreapp3.1 I do get the hint, with net452 I don't). As a workaround you could set the language version explicitly - don't know enough about unity to know what that would be though.

Answer (score 8):

This will work:

```
double value1 = stateExample switch
    {
        State.ExampleA => (double)BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes((long)2147483646), 0), //Commenting this line results in correct value
        State.ExampleB => BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes((long)2147483647), 0),
        State.ExampleC => BitConverter.ToInt16(BitConverter.GetBytes((long)2147483648), 0),
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
    };
```

`BitConverter.ToSingle`  returns `float` so compiler [infers](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=) `float` (between `float`, `uint` and `short`) as output type for the switch expression (and casting `uint` and `short` to it) and then casts it's result to `double` which results in precision loss for `ExampleB` case.

Answer (score 0):

Like probably others, I also came to this question because I really got surprised by these semantics of switch expressions. Here's an example similar to what I had at first:

```cs
{
    object left = 1;
    object value;

    switch (left)
    {
        case int previousInt: // <-- this case gets used
            value = previousInt + 1;
            break;
        case double previousDouble:
            value = previousDouble + 2;
            break;
        default:
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    // Output:
    // 2
    // System.Int32 (expected)
    Console.WriteLine(value);
    Console.WriteLine(value.GetType());
}
```

Now, my IDE (JetBrains Rider) suggested that I could convert this to a switch expression. The end result is something like this:

```cs
{
    object left = 1;

    object value = left switch
    {
        int previousInt => previousInt + 1, // <-- this "case" gets used
        double previousDouble => previousDouble + 2,
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
    };

    // Output:
    // 2
    // System.Double (NOT what I expected)
    Console.WriteLine(value);
    Console.WriteLine(value.GetType());
}
```

The root cause of this is the same as posted in this question. An expression has a single type, and `double` and `int` can both be implicitly converted to `double` (but *not* to `int`!) => this is the target type of the expression chosen by the C# compiler.

---

**Bottom line**: Be very careful when using switch expressions, especially when using loosely typed variables like `object` in my use case. It's probably much better (and safer) to write out the type of the variable in this case, to make it more obvious to the reader (hey, that's *you* just a few days/weeks/months from now on!) how the code works.