# Weird(?) behavior while using c# switch expression

Tags: c#, type-resolution

I noticed this while using c#'s switch expressions; I'd like to know if this is by design, or something else altogether.

```cs
public interface IBase
{
}

public struct Base1: IBase
{
    //fields, methods, etc
}

public struct Base2: IBase
{
    //fields, methods, etc
}

public struct BaseContainer: IBase
{
    public IBase InnerBase{get;}

    public BaseContainer(IBase value)
    {
        //validation and other goodies...
        InnerBase = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator BaseContainer(Base1 value) => new BaseContainer(value);

    public static implicit operator BaseContainer(Base2 value) => new BaseContainer(value);
}

public class Util
{
    public static IBase NewBase(int somethingToSwitchOn)
    {
        return somethingToSwitchOn switch
        {
            1 => new Base1(),
            2 => new Base2(),
            _ => default(BaseContainer)
        };
    }
}
```

Here's where it gets weird:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var @base = Util.NewBase(1);
    
    Console.WriteLine(@base.GetType().Name);
}
```

The above code outputs "BaseContainer", instead of "Base1" as expected, until **ANY** of the switch steps is explicitly casted to `IBase`, e.g:

```cs
1 => new Base1(),
2 => (IBase) new Base2(),
_ => default(BaseContainer)
```

Comment: I am new to C# and your syntax does not look quite C# to me. Anyway, isn't switch suposed to have a "Break ;" on each option?

Comment: @MundoPeter It's the new `switch` expression https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression

Comment: @MundoPeter The [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) was introduced with C# 8.0.

Comment: Look at your `public static implicit operator BaseContainer`. It casts your Base1/Base2 type to `BaseContainer` type

Comment: It's basically happening because the `switch` is trying to find a common type to cast or convert all the results to, and the `implicit` conversion is available. Can't find the exact language spec just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler needs to figure out a type for the switch expression. Its type can't be `Base1`, `Base2` *and* `BaseContainer` at the same time, after all.

To do this, it [finds the best common type of the expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#finding-the-best-common-type-of-a-set-of-expressions) in each of switch expression's arms. According to the specification, the type is the same type as the type inferred when calling a generic method like this:

```
Tr M<X>(X x1 ... X xm)
```

with the expressions of the switch expression's arms passed as arguments.

I won't go into the details of type inference, but in general it is quite intuitive (as it is here). The best common type for `new Base1()`, `new Base2()`, and `default(BaseContainer)` is `BaseContainer`, and the best common type for `new Base1()`, `(IBase)new Base2()`, and `default(BaseContainer)` is `IBase`.

So if you don't cast, then the switch expression produces a `BaseContainer`, which means that the new `Base1` object you created has to be converted to a `BaseContainer` first. This calls your implicit operator, which returns a `BaseContainer` object, and so `GetType` returns `BaseContainer`.

If you cast any of the arms to `IBase`, then the whole switch expression produces `IBase`. Converting from `Base1` to `IBase` is a [boxing conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#boxing-conversions), and so doesn't change its dynamic type (i.e. what `GetType` returns).

Comment: Thanks. This does make sense. I initially assumed it will infer the common type as IBase, from the return type of the function, rather than BaseContainer.

Comment: @Dantte Ah so that's your misunderstanding. Interestingly, the return type _can_ matter (though it does not in these two cases because the type can be inferred solely from the arms). See [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63257017/5133585).

Answer (score 2):

This is all to do with type inference. The fact that there is an implicit conversion from both `Base1` and `Base2` to `BaseContainer` means that it will be considered first, before a possible boxing conversion to an interface.

We can see the language spec talking about this

> [**Finding the best common type of a set of expressions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#finding-the-best-common-type-of-a-set-of-expressions)
>
> *..snip..*
> More precisely, the inference starts out with an *unfixed type variable* `X`. *Output type inferences* are then made *from* each `Ei` *to* `X`. Finally, `X` is **fixed** and, if successful, the resulting type `S` is the resulting best common type for the expressions. If no such `S` exists, the expressions have no best common type.

What is fixing?

> [**Fixing**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#fixing)
>
> An unfixed type variable `Xi` with a set of bounds is fixed as follows:
>
> - The set of candidate types `Uj` starts out as the set of all types in the set of bounds for `Xi`.
> - We then examine each bound for `Xi` in turn: *..snip..* For each lower bound `U` of `Xi` all types `Uj` to which there is not an implicit conversion from `U` are removed from the candidate set. For each upper bound `U` of `Xi` all types `Uj` from which there is not an implicit conversion to `U` are removed from the candidate set.
> - If among the remaining candidate types `Uj` there is a unique type V from which there is an implicit conversion to all the other candidate types, then Xi is fixed to V.

Comment: Fixing -  this answers the question I actually had in mind: "why chose the implicit conversion over the common interface...?"

Thanks.

Comment: @Dantte Fixing is not the answer to that. "[Implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#implicit-conversions)" in the terminology of the specs includes conversions from classes to interfaces that they implement too. Specifically, it's called an "implicit reference conversion", your implicit conversion operator would be referred to as a "user-defined implicit conversion". Your question can be answered by the first quote from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63257514/5133585).

Comment: @Dantte In short, the type of the switch expression is figured out from the arms. If that fails, _then_ it looks at the return type.